Would manufacturing steel in space be more energy efficient?
A company want to move the production processes of their company into space. More specifically, it is a company that mainly refines iron ore into workable steel. Recently, they have been wondering if moving their production off world would make it more energy efficient.
This is mostly based on 2 things:

The slower heat loss in space as only radiative heat escapes, which might be further limited.
In the production of steel, multiple techniques are used which use (partial) vacuums.

They are wiling to settle the production facilities on the moon or another planet/moon/large-asteroid without atmosphere- to provide gravity- if this would help the production process. (likely a large asteroid, to allow for movement of the fabrication facilities).
Ignore initial setup costs and difficulties, and assuming the supply of resources(iron rich asteroids, carbon rich asteroids) to be large enough.
Would setting up a factory in space be more energy efficient in its production processes (compared to Earth counterparts)?

Where does the heat come from (is there a decent mains gas supply out there)? How do you separate the slag without gravity? Where do you get the carbon/gasses? Can you detail the process you're proposing - or is that the question, do you want us to design the power-system/processing for you?

@Escapeddentalpatient. For the carbon, they harvest it from other astroids (assume there is enough). I was mostly thinking about a fusion reactor as energy source. Using either inductive or direct heating for the iron (but it isn’t limited to that, as other forms might be more efficient). Keeping the metal in place with magnetic fields. Using convection to move about the out impurities. Vacuum induction melting uses are my inspiration for this process, but now it is also used to keep in place/move the materials.

Steel is not made by refining iron ore. Super-refined iron ore is not steel, it is ultra-pure rust. (1) I do not understand the idea behind the importance of energy efficiency. Energy efficiency starting from what? It is one thing to start from iron ore and coal, and a very different thing to start from already molten pig iron. Needs clarity. (2) Where do they get the iron ore from in outer space? Iron ore is some sort of iron oxide. Earth has lots of it, Mars has lots of it, the Moon does not have any at all. Some asteroids might be made of some sort of iron-nickel alloy...

Convection - relies on a gravitational gradient. How would convection occur in zero G?

Location has an implied energy cost, and transporting (heavy) steel from one place to another is going to be very expensive in energy, so you'd have to run more than a small surplus in the actual production to make up the difference.  There was a news story a while back about an asteroid believed to have trillions of dollars of platinum in it, but the cost of going and fetching it is apparently higher.

Are you asking about mining ore on planet, lifting it up to orbit and shipping it back?
Under what what tech level are they operating? (If they have scifi antigravity, that changes  things allot) Where does the ore come from where is it going. Not  a bad question but needs more detail.

@AlexP It might not be directly processed into steel, I thought there were steel-making plants that directly processed iron ore into steel, keeping the metal hot when going to the next step. The 'energy efficiency' is my excuse for the move from earth based to space based production. I expected the process to cost less energy per product produced, as the vacuum of space could be directly used instead of artificial vacuum, and expected heat loss to be lower than on Earth. With a side note that the produced metals are likely to be used spacecrafts, so not airlifting them would be a boon.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I would have them settle on a large asteroid if the production process needs it, but wouldn't the differences in heat, and its own mass be enough? (I might need to ask a question on how to produce steel in space...) If not, wouldn't the induction coils we use to hold the mass in place/heat it up be used to make the metal flow too?

Sure, you could spin it and create the necessary buoyancy forces to get the slag out. Large asteroids would provide tiny gravity - can you wait for months for the slag to rise?

@Gillgamesh I am asking about astroid mining, processing that into steel from raw ore, all in space. Tech level is slightly more advanced than today. I am willing to believe any theoretically plausible theory, as long as it is science-based.

@Escapeddentalpatient. If the production is in high enough quantities. Could I set one spinning, while starting the next batch? Could I create gigantic spheres/globs of materials? Would the heat naturally make the oxygen escape? Maybe just spin it faster and take the loss in efficiency... So many questions. Gonna sit down and try to format the production process into another question to ask.

The major benefits in steel production space is not the energy its the microgravity. Enabling materials like "glasssteel" and "foam steel" to be produced. A good google with  the term "manufacturing in space" will help, and a good site for ideas: https://www.factoriesinspace.com/

Solar power.
It's not efficient on earth because there's too much atmosphere in the way.  Space?  Go solar!

If you're producing steel in space to use in construction in space, from metal you mined in space, the "not lifting the steel into space" is almost definitely sufficient justification to produce the steel in space, even if the actual production is significantly more difficult.

This entire question seems based on the premise that vacuum can't be produced on planets. Vacuum processing is actually used to produce some specialized alloys, including steels, but it's done down on the ground, using pumps to produce the vacuum.

On one condition: yes. Space is where you want to use the steel you produce.
The cost of producing steel on Earth (even in terms of energy) is far exceeded by the cost of boosting anything made from it off the Earths surface and up into orbit (both financially and in terms of the energy budget). Likewise while dropping a load of steel from orbit down to the surface is cheap (energetically) in comparison you still have to get that load of steel back to Earth. And that means either moving the asteroid into an orbit around Earth or shipping the steel back to Earth first (both of which require additional energy expenditure).
So assuming you have spaced based mining and processing facilities? Any steel you produce would only be 'cheaper' if it was used exclusively for space based construction projects.  Basically? Your company would need customers in space to make it worth while.

No
I'm answering only because I'm on the fence about voting to close the question as either opinion-based or needs more details. No question about efficiency is simple, and you've left out a LOT of details. Saying that almost convinced me to VTC.

Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space. –Douglas Adams

You might not have the problems with weight as you do on Earth, but you're still expending energy to move the mass. And you're moving that mass over mind-blowing distances, which means you're either giving up time or energy. Unless you hand-wave the magical appearance of an all-iron asteroid that falls into orbit around the moon, you're hauling ore either from the surface of the Earth (384,400 km + lift cost out of gravity well) or from the asteroid belt (at least 150 MILLION km assuming the asteroid is in the right place).
The truth is that while asteroid mining and space construction sound cool in stories, the only reason anybody in their right mind would do it is because you need VAST quantities of (e.g.) steel and can put the manufacturing right next to the ore source. The moon is completely unrealistic.
Well... there might be a way...
You said we could ignore startup dependencies. Great! If (and it's a whomping big if) a very large source of iron could be found in the asteroid belt (because it'll never be cost or energy efficient to haul it out of the gravity well), then we could give it just enough of a push from the asteroid belt that it would eventually transit near the moon for recapture without a lot of expended energy. That might actually work... if...

You're willing to wait for the first shipment to arrive. If we accelerate a ton of ore to 1,000 km/s or 3.6 million km/hr and decelerate it when it gets to the moon the straight-line transit time is 17+ days... the transfer orbit will not be a straight line, so it could be months (or even years) for the first shipment to arrive. I can't believe that would be more energy efficient... but the lower the velocity, the longer that first shipment takes to arrive and there are some positions of Earth, moon, and asteroid where there may not be a transfer orbit.

You're willing to live with an Archimedean spiral of iron ore circling in all along the asteroid belt to Earth orbit. Talk about a navigational nightmare because the ore shipments must be large enough and frequent enough for this make sense. And this whole idea is an apocalypse waiting to happen. Guess where the ore goes if the capture process fails?


And I'm already having suspension of disbelief problems. You'd exhaust even a large asteroid's source of iron long before this distribution channel filled up enough to make any of this work with a more efficient energy budget than just doing it on Earth.
You tagged this science-based. Yes, you're only asking about energy efficiency, but that's ignoring all the rest of science. This solution would never be efficient unless the source was large and close to the manufacturing facility and the user of the steel was also close to the manufacturing facility. Heaven help you if we need to start factoring in the efficiencies of dropping a useful amount of steel into the Earth's gravity well (The U.S. uses about 90 million tons annually or a bit under 250,000 tons a day).
So, no, it wouldn't be efficient compared to the Earth-bound solutions unless you have story conditions that bring quantity, distribution, capability, and purpose all together into the same place.
Space is big... really, really, really big.

To be fair, the OP linked to a NASA article in his/her next post that proves there is an asteroid that would act as a practical source. Cheers!

Umm, there are 3,600 seconds in one hour. 150,000,000 km divided by 1,000 km/s is only 150,000 seconds or about 42 hours. On the other hand, 1,000 km/s is 3,600,000 km/h, which is rather more than 60,000 km/h.

So, having the facilities on the moon would be a big no. And I need to be closer to the asteroids, maybe even starting on a large rock part of an asteroid-belt. Placing the facilities on a large asteroid -very near an asteroid belt- but on a slower orbit, so the belt rotates 'near' it. Ejecting waste matter to retain the changed orbit from collecting asteroids. The Archimedean spiral sounds 'fun', maybe I could use that to move steel to the moon for processing into actual goods. As for a VTC, might be for the best, as efficient is an nebulous concept, how would I improve that?

@vinzzz001 Frankly, the real problem is that you appear to be seeking a scientific or legitimate reason to place manufacturing in space, so you looked for an efficiency comparison between Earth-bound and space-based manufacturing. From a Real Life perspective that's a meaningless request. By the time we have the technology to (e.g.) place manufacturing on the moon, the basis of all efficiencies will have changed with it. Our guessing what those changes would be is equally meaningless and anybody who could legitimately explain it would be running to... (*Continued*)

... the patent office, not posting the explanation here. Worldbuilding is about rationalization and balance, not reality (thank goodness). From that perspective this question doesn't even make sense. What's stopping you from placing manufacturing on the moon? Only your imagination and a basic explanation of how you use the tech. Nothing more (especially not a justification that you're right).

@AlexP Yeah... I pounded that out a bit fast. My calculator said 17.something and my brain said, "see! Decades!" when it was days. I've made the correction. Thanks for pointing it out.

Cheaper no, but better? Maybe
I will assume we are comparing the cost of making steel on Earth for consumption on Earth vs making Steel in Space for consumption in Space since assuming using one to make for the other is going to be a horribly unfair comparison given transit costs.
The first thing to consider about steel making is that it is actually a 2 part process, and each part has advantages and disadvantages when doing it in space.
First you need to smelt the steel
Smelting is the process by which you melt ore and isolate the specific metal(s) that you wish to turn into to something.  This part is almost certainly better to do on Earth.
For starters, micro gravity makes this process much more expensive, not cheaper.  It adds an extra cost because on Earth, gravity is precisely the free energy source that allows you to seperate the heavy and light elements in iron ore via distillation.  So, if you want to separate iron in space you need to create artificial gravity by spinning your iron in a giant centrifuge which consumes a lot of energy that you don't have to worry about here on Earth.
This part is also a lot harder because you need a fluxing material.  Even if you set up shop somewhere nearby two separate ferrous and carbonations asteroid so that you have a  plentiful carbon source to flux and alloy your steel, the asteroid belt is not nearly as dense as the movies make it seem. The average distance between any given asteroid and its closest neighbor is about 1 million kilometers which means you need to spend a lot on transporting you carbon source to your smelter compared to on Earth where good iron ore and carbon sources are typically within 1000 kilometers of each other.
That said... not having an atmosphere could have certain advantages in this stage.  If your centrifuge is just a big disc shaped crucible floating in space then there is no friction to slow it down once it gets up to speed; so, it should spin as long as you need it to until it is time to slow it back down.  Secondly, heat can only escape by radiation since there is no medium for heat to escape by convection; so, you will not lose much heat to inefficiencies while trying to get your temperature up.
Next you need to temper it
Tempering is the process by which to take your metal and heat/cool it in ways that create the exact crystal structure that you want.  The best steels involve several cycles of heating and cooling to achieve the desired outcome.  On Earth, steels are cooled either by the air, in water, or in oil.  In space, all of these are VERY hard materials to come by in industrially useful quantities; so, all of the energy you've saved by being in a vacuum will actually come back here to bite you in the bum here because if you cool the steel too slowly, it will anneal making it too soft and malleable for most practical purposes.  So, you will need to spend a significant amount of money creating and maintaining an artificial fluid environment to rapidly cool your steel in; so, the one advantage you had in the smelting stage becomes an even bigger disadvantage when refining.
Despite all of these drawbacks, there is still the potential to make a better quality steel in space.  When steel sets on earth, it does not crystalize in a perfectly symmetrical way because it is forming under gravity.  Denser elements might settle to the bottom a bit during cooling causing one side of a metal object to have slightly different properties than the other, or at the molecular level, there may be some breaks in the crystal lattice due to sagging.  These impurities are barely perceptible, but can slightly weaken or warp steels that are refined under gravity.  So if you make your steel in microgravity, there may be a few very specific high performance parts that would noticably benefit from the microgravity environment during this phase of production.
